# What's the highest temperature that algae can survive at?

Tags: plant-physiology

I know there are a lot of different species of algae and that each one has different environmental tolerances. I've seen data on different species:

- brown alga *Sargassum echinocarpum* J. Agardh - grows well at 35°
- *Dictyopteris australis* - grows poorly above 28°
- halophilic blue-green algae *A. fertilissima* - temperatures of 47° stimulates germination

What's the highest temperature that growing algae or its spores can survive at? In other words, what temperature would guarantee that no algae could grow afterwards unless reintroduced?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the habitat of Algaes, a classification called "Thermophytes" can bear high temperature. The Thermophyte algaes use to grow around hot springs and can live around 70°C.

Please find below the reference for all classifications and more details.

http://www.yourarticlelibrary.com/biology/8-types-of-algae-classified-according-to-their-habitats/7098/

http://www.biologydiscussion.com/essay/essay-on-algae/20891